# RecyclerView notifyItemRemoved() Animation Error

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have a linear RecyclerView in a Fragment in a ViewPager. I have a `onSwiped()` callback to allow swipe-to-dismiss UI. I want to confirm the delete first, so I have an interface that returns `boolean` from my ViewPager (HomeActivity) after an alert dialog response. I want the swipe to animate a dataset change if true and replace the item view if false. But the animation does not work, even with both `notifyItemRemoved()` and `notifyItemRangeChanged()` called. I am having trouble using the libraries I found so I am doing it this way for now.

Can someone help me figure out why?

**ListFragment.class**

```
public class ListFragment extends Fragment {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private SongRecyclerViewAdapter recyclerViewAdapter;
    private FragmentCommunicator communicator;

    public ListFragment() {
        // Required empty constructor
    }

    public static ListFragment newInstance() {
        return new ListFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof FragmentCommunicator) {
            communicator = (FragmentCommunicator) context;
        } else {
        throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                + " must implement FragmentCommunicator");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_song_list, container, false);

        // Set the adapter
        if (view instanceof RecyclerView) {
            Context context = view.getContext();
            recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view;
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
            recyclerViewAdapter = new SongRecyclerViewAdapter(communicator.getList(), communicator);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter);
        }

        SimpleCallback simpleItemCallBack = new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT) {
            @Override
            public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
                int pos = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
                // this is my problem
                if (communicator.remove(pos)) { // goes to HomeActivity.class
                    // this use to work until I wrapped it in the above condition
                    recyclerViewAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(pos);
                    recyclerViewAdapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(pos, recyclerViewAdapter.getItemCount());
                }
            }
        };

        ItemTouchHelper itemTouchHelper = new ItemTouchHelper(simpleItemCallBack);
        itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        // kill
        communicator = null;
        recyclerViewAdapter = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your FragmentCommunicator returning `true` when you call `communicator.remove(pos)`?

Comment: @Disco S2 it is if the user clicks yes on the alert dialog that pops up and false other wise. I have tested the data and it is removed on true but not animation

Comment: So `communicator.remove(pos)` displays an `AlertDialog` which in it's confirmation onClickListener you return the result? This could be the issue. Try instead, showing the AlertDialog in this onSwiped and in it's onClick callbacks call your notifyItemRemoved code

Comment: @Disco S2 Ok Ok. That makes sense. Then if true use communicator to change the dataset? I'll try it out

Comment: @Disco S2 That didnt work. Have little to no idea why its like that